# can't install capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, makefile, g++, capybara-webkit

When I `bundle install` I get:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec linux-g++ ' not available

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/bundler20141128-11764-1rcu7gh/capybara-w
ebkit-1.3.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/bundler20141128-11764-1rcu7gh/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/exten
sions/x86-linux/2.1.0/capybara-webkit-1.3.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.3.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.3.0'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a little late to the game, but I ran into a similar problem getting a legacy Rails app running on my local dev machine, running Debian.  It turned out that not only did it require qmake and a qt-default package installed, but it specifically required qt4-qmake and qt4-default; qt5-qmake and qt5-default would not do the job.  Perhaps the OP's issue revolved around lacking qmake and whatever equivalent of Debian's qt-default packages exist on the relevant distribution, or selecting the wrong Qt version for qmake and qt-default.